# Where can I edit my app's Terms of Service and EULA in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play

My app's Terms of Service and EULA has been changed. I would like to edit it. But for some reason I don't see any edit texts which I could modify to actually change my links.

Please someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been moved to the policy section:

1. Open your app in the publisher dashboard
2. Look for **Policy** in the menu
3. Click **App content**
4. Look for **Privacy Policy**
5. Click **Manage** to update your privacy policy URL

[image: Screenshot of the Play Console]